# scroll effect with labels using delay C#

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, label

I have a problem. I need to create a scroll effect with labels. The essence is to put the value to label with 1 sec delay.
I have a function which generates for each label number of the array. But it occurs immediately and I tried to make a delay. I used `Timer` but it doesn't give me any results or I just don't know how to use it correctly. Also tried to use `Thread.Sleep()` but it doesn't give me expected result.

```
public void generator() // присваивание текстбоксам значений 
    {
        int[] array = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();
        green = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            panel1.Controls[i].Text = array[i].ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            panel1.Controls[i].Refresh();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow currentRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell currentCell in currentRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(currentCell.Value) == array[i] && currentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                    {
                        currentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        green++;
                        panel1.Controls[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20)` - this function generates an array from 1 to 80 and returns 20 numbers.

When I use `Thread.Sleep(350)` I press the button and the form is freezing then each label gets a value from an array with delay 350ms. If I press this button one more time the current value replaces previous value without cleaning previous values though I clean them with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            panel1.Controls[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            panel1.Controls[i].Text = null;
        }
```

It is my actual result. But I expect to do described instructions without freezing from and in another thread that will allow me to use form while such circle is run.

And finally I'll try to explain more clearly:
I have 20 labels and 20 numbers. I need to assign each label the number with some delay - label1 = "1" -> (wait 1s) -> label2 = "2" -> (wait 1s) ... etc.

I would be grateful for help :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you describe how it fails by giving expected and actual result.

Comment: done. i wish it helps to undertand my idea :)

Comment: You shouldn't call `Thread.Sleep` from the UI thread. Try making your method `async` and use `await Task.Delay()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make you generator() an async one:

```
generator();


private async void generator()
{
   //(...)

   for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
   {
      panel1.Controls[i].Text = array[i].ToString();
      panel1.Controls[i].Refresh();
      await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));

      //(...)

   }
}
```

About the comments:

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000))
```

is a non-blocking awaiter. It is possible, depending on the context, that the second Task might be context-unaware. If that is the case, this can be solved using ConfigureAwait().

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1200).ConfigureAwait(true)).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

The second async in `await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));` works as an Unwrap() method.

Usually, `Task.Factory.StartNew()` starts a new Task that runs in a different thread, and it returns immediately.
But using `.Unwrap()` on a `Task<Task><TResult>` gives you back a `Task<TResult>`, a proxy to the completion of the inner Task:

```
bool _task1 = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   return true;
}, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap<bool>();
```

So, followind the same logic, one can substitute the Unwrap() method with a new awaiter.

```
bool _task2 = await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   return true;
}, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Now `Task.Factory.StartNew()` returns a `Task<Task<bool>>`.
If you Await `Task<Task<bool>>`, it returns a `Task<bool>`, and again awaiting that Task, a bool is returned.

But, if you don't need a type result:

```
await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
}, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000))
```

Comment: Isn't there a chance that the code after `await` will end up running on a different thread (which won't be able to update the UI)?

Comment: @John Wu  Nope. Task.Run() creates a new Thread which is awaited by the current, which will continue only after the Delay(). It's non-blocking and the UI will update gracefully.

Comment: Are you sure?  When I run [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9EJMI1) which parallels your code, I get three different thread IDs in the output. Just trying to understand.

Comment: @John Wu Well, I don't know about that website, but testing it in Visual Studio, the ThreadID is always the same. IsThreadPoolThread is always false.

Comment: Yeah it is not 100% consistent, but I get the same issue in Visual Studio too. Maybe you should run it a few times. If Delay didn't allow for running on a different thread, how could it ensure timing (e.g. if the UI thread is busy at the time the delay elapses)?

Comment: @John Wu  Task.Run() creates a new thread, that is assured. So Task.Delay() executes in this thread, detached from UI thread. The UI may be busy before running the Task or after the delay has elapsed, but will always wait for it to complete. I have run 10 times that code, and the results are the same. Which FW version are you using? (4.7.1 here).

Comment: .NET 4.5.2 console application. I've been trying to figure this out for a while. `Delay` sets up a system timer and a callback, which is what calls the task completion method; I am pretty sure there is no guarantee of threading context when it gets called. Problem even happens if you use `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160472/discussion-between-jimi-and-john-wu).

Comment: it also works but the same problem as an example in previous comment

Comment: @Syncmaxim  Try to set a higher delay. I've tested it, and both examples  work as expected. Maybe, in your code, you are doing something that you're not showing here.

Comment: You do not need to use `Task.Run` or create a thread to use `Task.Delay`. In fact that is counterproductive since the thread will immediately block. Just call `await Task.Delay(1000)`.

Comment: @Dour High Arch  The second `async/await` prevents this. You could say that the first time that Task is run, there is a chance that the Delay() task might be context-unaware. But this is not blocking at all. I'll make an edit, to show some equivalent solutions.

Comment: @Jimi in general your method is really helpful but it couse conflict with some my functions. i'll try to fix them or will find new method to solve it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `Timer` control on the form.  The trick is to let the timer `Tick` event replace the outer loop, such that each "tick" of the timer performs one iteration.  Follow these steps:

1. Add a `Timer` control to your form.  I'll assume here it is called `timer1`.
2. In the timer properties, set the `Interval` to 1000.  This will cause it to "tick" once per second.  Be sure the `Enabled` property is set to `False`.
3. Add a couple of private fields to your form to keep track of the generated array of numbers and the index of the next label to be populated:

   ```
   private int[] generatedArray;
   private int nextControlIndex = 0;
   ```
4. Double-click on the timer in the form to add a `Tick` event handler.  In the handler, add the following code:

   ```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int i = nextControlIndex++;
       if (i < panel1.Controls.Count && i < generatedArray.Length)
       {
           panel1.Controls[i].Text = generatedArray[i].ToString();

           foreach (DataGridViewRow currentRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {
               foreach (DataGridViewCell currentCell in currentRow.Cells)
               {
                   if (Convert.ToInt32(currentCell.Value) == generatedArray[i] && 
                       currentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                   {
                       currentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                       green++;
                       panel1.Controls[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       else
       {
           timer1.Stop();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally, change the code for your `generator()` method to set up the private fields and start the timer:

   ```
   public void generator() // присваивание текстбоксам значений 
   {
       generatedArray = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();
       nextControlIndex = 0;
       green = 0;
       timer1.Start();
   }
   ```

And that's it.  Now the labels should get populated incrementally whenever you call the `generator()` function.

Comment: thanks, it works but now i have the problem that green color assign faster then timer stops. and some other UI problems connected with this timer.